# understanding std::thread semantic with worker function as class member

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

To implement the logic when contructed object starts background thread for real work, I'm using a pattern like this (simplified):

```
class A {
    std::thread t{&A::run, this};
    std::atomic_bool done;
    // variables are the question about
    std::vector<std::thread>  array_for_thread_management;

    // ... and other members
protected:
    void run() {
        ...
        array_for_thread_management.push_back([](){...});
        ...
   }
public:
    A() = default;
    // all other constructors deleted because of used 
    // some members like std::atomic_bool done;
    ~A() {
        done = true;
        bi::named_condition         cnd{bi::open_only, "cnd"};
        cnd.notify_one();

        if (t.joinable())
            t.join();

        for(std::thread& worker : array_for_thread_management) {
            if (worker.joinable()) worker.join();
        }
    }


};
```

If I'm adding a push of child threads in primary background thread into a vector in run() member, the object hangs on destructor. 
even there is no real threads in a vector, just started this without connections from outside and try to stop this by destructor

Comment: You're asking how to access member variables from within a member function? The only thing special here is you need to ensure there's no concurrent access to `s`, `v` etc from multiple threads. If you need that, you'll need to introduce a `mutex`.

Comment: that's helpful, just want to confirm that sync the access the only thing in this case. thank you. let me extend the question to clarify this

Comment: @amigo421 Your question is a bit too vague. Do you also have access to your plain members for public use? Should `done` wake up other threads waiting for this one? In the latter case you probably want to use a condition variable instead of an atomic.

Comment: `A::run()` is a normal member function so you access members normally. The fact you happen to run it in a new thread doesn't affect the _syntax_ of how you write it (but as said above, you need to be careful about its semantics and how it accesses data shared with other threads).

Comment: have you checked in the debugger which join() it is blocking at?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, once you have `this` pointer in your `run` method, you can access class members via this pointer. I guess the problem with your code is that the thread is spawned *before* any other members are initialized, as it is the first member in your class definition. I suspect with the following definition of `class A` you'll have no problems with accessing member variables:

```
class A {
    std::atomic_bool done;
    // variables are the question about
    int i;
    std::string s;
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    // and only after everything above is initialized:
    std::thread t{&A::run, this}; // spawn a thread
    // ...
}
```

However, personally I would prefer having a separate method `start()` which spawns a thread to spawning it inside class constructor implicitly. It may look like this:

```
class A
{
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> t;
    std::atomic<bool> some_flag;

public:
    void start()
    {
        t.reset(new std::thread(&A::run, this));
    }

private:
    void run()
    {
        some_flag.store(true);
    }
};
```